# Get JSON object from URL (Shopify)

Tags: php, json, shopify

I want to make a display that shows the revenue of my webshop.
I am using shopify and can access my data in a JSON file using their API, and it looks like this:

```
{"orders":[{
"id":2873739739288,
"email":"example@gmail.com",
----- many more lines -----
"total_price":"29.95"
}]}
```

I need to get the total_price value from this part.
I currently am using this script, but I get no results.

```
<?
$json = file_get_contents('https://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@MYSHOPNAME.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/orders.json?limit=5');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->total_price;
?>
```

So how can I retrieve it through PHP? Right now I just get a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_price` is not a property of `$obj`, but of an item in your `orders` array. To access this property, you have to go to the correct level:

```
$json = '{"orders":[{
"id":2873739739288,
"email":"example@gmail.com",
"total_price":"29.95"
}]}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->orders[0]->total_price; // This will output 29.95.
```

In that last line `$obj->orders[0]` is used to get the property `orders` from the object, and of that property `orders` (which is an array), you use the first item of the array with `[0]`. Remember the first item of an array has the key `0` and not `1`, because arrays in PHP (as in just about all programming languages I believe) are zero based (also called zero-indexed), meaning you start counting from zero. Finally, on the first item of your array (which is another object) you want to access `total price`, for which you use `->total_price`.

Comment: Thank you very much!  @Dirk J Faber
I now get the correct results.
Let's say I want to see more results, can I use a foreach function?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would do.